Datagridview - adding a space in a cell triggers a whole new form
This is a new one to me, and I couldn't find anything on it.
I have a simple form in c# with a datagridview. In the Form_Load i read a table from a drawing and populate the form with the text from the table.
Now, I have created no events except a simple button, but the button is not used in this process. There are no other events in the form at all.
So, the issue is, I select a cell in the datagridview and go to edit it. Whenever the space key or the enter key are hit, it launches a whole new version of the form. For the life of me, I cannot figure out why.
This is the code that launches the dialog (a button on a ribbon):
override protected void ButtonDefinition_OnExecute(NameValueMap context)
{
    EditRevisionTableForm rtf = new EditRevisionTableForm();
    rtf.Show();
}

And this is the code in the Form:
public EditRevisionTableForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void EditRevisionTableForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DrawingDocument oDoc = (DrawingDocument)Globals._InvApp.ActiveEditDocument;

    RevisionTable revtable;

    foreach (Sheet sheet in oDoc.Sheets)
    {
        sheet.Activate();
        revtable = oDoc.ActiveSheet.RevisionTables[1];

        foreach (RevisionTableRow rtRow in revtable.RevisionTableRows)
        {
            List<string> celllist = new List<string>();
            foreach (RevisionTableCell cell in rtRow)
            {
                celllist.Add(cell.Text);
            }                    
            dgvRevTable.Rows.Add(true, celllist[0], celllist[1], celllist[2], celllist[3], celllist[4], celllist[5]);
        }
    }
}

As I said, no other events are called, but trying to add a space or hitting enter in any field triggers a whole new instance of the form and I can see no reason why.  Any ideas?
My expectation here is that I could edit a field to have spaces in it. I have no other events, though I tried adding some key events to no avail. I've restarted the machine thinking maybe something was conflicting, but no luck there either.

Perhaps add a breakpoint in the form constructor, then you may be able to see how it’s being created

OK, i cannot explain this.  This is part of an add-in to a program. I have 40ish commands in this application and they were all working fine - just this new one was doing this weird thing with spaces. Debug turned up nothing. So i tried a variety of things. But in the end, i deleted the first file containing the button definition and recreated it from scratch (a whopping 10 lines of code or so) and problem solved.  My best guess is some sort of corruption in the file? However you would think that would show errors, no act as a key event for the whole form...
